# Angular2: string value rendered as an integer when binding to a template

Tags: angular

Consider the following piece of Angular2 code:

`<li *ngFor='let department of departments' value='{{department.id}}'>{{department.name}} {{department.id}}</li>`

When I run it in the browser, it renders the following html (cleaned up for clarity):

```
<li value="-1677026285">Dept1 2617941011</li>
```

Notice that the same variable, `department.id` is rendered as its actual value of 2617941011 in the text portion of the `li`, but as something entirely different in the `value` attribute (looks like it attempted to parse that string as an integer).

Is there any way to avoid it?

I will add that the `Department` class (of which `departments` is an array of) specifies `id` as a strongly typed property:

```
    export class Department {constructor(public name:string = "", public id:string = ""){ }}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide plukr for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li value='{{department.id}}'></li>
```

This code means that you pass value **property** on li element.

From this [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_li_value.asp)

> The value property sets or returns the value of the value attribute of
>   a list item.

Then look at this specification:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-li-element

> The value attribute, if present, must be a valid integer giving the
>   ordinal value of the list item.

It should be number from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`

> If the value attribute is present, user agents must [parse it](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#rules-for-parsing-integers) as an
>   integer

So there is nothing related with angular2

Use attribute binding instead:

```
[attr.value]="department.id"
```

Comment: That makes sense, but any idea how to work around it?

Comment: Try `[attr.value]='department.id'`

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you! I then had to access it from the component as 
`$event.target.attributes['value'].value` 
as opposed to just 
`$event.target.value`
which is what I was doing pre-workaround.